# Does Modifiying Vertex Weights automatically update animations?

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, weight-painting, vertex-weights

Let's say I have a figure rigged and weight painted in a rough way. I then make some quick animations first, and then go back and fine tune the vertex weights on the mesh. Will the animations automatically reflect the newly fine tuned weights on the mesh?

If not, is there a way to update the animations to reflect the new weights without having to redo the animations completely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Of course, it will be updated. In fact, it is a good way to fine tune the rigging.

You can change bones as well within reasonable limits.